# Cygwin - error loading shared library: arm-elf-gcc.exe from GNUARM

Tags: linux, cygwin, matlab, arm, shared-libraries

I have installed Embedded Robot Coder, a set of tools for developing embedded ARM applications, e. g. for Lego NXT brick, using MATLAB on Windows. It contains Cygwin, GNUARM utilities and so on. When I try compile my application, generating C code works fine, but while building, an error occurs:

`Compiling /cygdrive/C/MATLAB/2013/ecrobotnxt/environment/nxtOSEK/toppers_osek/kernel/alarm.c to alarm.o
C:/cygwin64/GNUARM/bin/arm-elf-gcc.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I opened Cygwin Terminal (but Cugwin utilities also works on Windows CMD), and run `ldd` on arm-elf-gcc.exe. Output is following:

`$  ldd ./arm-elf-gcc.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fff9c3e0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x778e0000)
        wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/wow64.dll (0x77800000)
        wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/wow64win.dll (0x77860000)`

What does `???` mean? I also used `cygcheck` command. On Windows CMD output is following:

`C:\cygwin64\GNUARM\bin>cygcheck arm-elf-gcc.exe
Found: arm-elf-gcc.exe
arm-elf-gcc.exe`

...but on Cygwin Terminal cygcheck returned an error:

`cygcheck.exe arm-elf-gcc.exe
cygcheck: could not find 'arm-elf-gcc.exe'`

While I was installing Cygwin I skipped many things just to save time and space, but I checked all necessary packages for ECR toolbox.

NOTE: That question is related to specific Matlab and Lego toolbox, but I ask it here because it uses Linux/Cygwin common mechanisms.

Comment: try `cygcheck.exe ./arm-elf-gcc.exe` from where the compiler is located

Comment: Thanks, I forgotten about adding ./ . But now it shows nothing special, same output as on Windows

Comment: The wow64.dll indicates that is a 32bit program on a 64bit system so the cygcheck 64 bit is not useful anyway. You can try with `objdump -x ./arm-elf-gcc.exe | grep DLL`

Comment: `objdump` shows cygwin1.dll, cygintl-3.dll and KERNEL32.dll libraries. Interesting thing is when I try to run arm-elf-gcc from command prompt Windows show error message that cygintl-3.dll is missing.

Comment: you need to find the libintl3 package from a previous 32bit distribution. http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround. I have installed 32-bit, instead of 64, version of Cygwin, and everything works. The problem possibly was connected to GNUARM compiler which "feels good" with 32-bit architecture. As @matzeri pointed, problematic libraries used 32-bit Windows dependencies.